# Kotlin Operator-Assignment

Tags: android, debugging, kotlin, operators

I've noticed some funny behavior with the Kotlin Operator-Assignment

```
var selectedIndex = 0
selectedIndex += selectedIndex
```

upon debugging, selected index still equals 0

When changed to

```
selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1
```

Android Studio complains about using an operator assignment but it functions as expected. What the hell is going on here??

Kotlin Version: 1.2.31

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var selectedIndex = 0
selectedIndex += selectedIndex
```

This could be rewritten as:

```
var selectedIndex = 0
selectedIndex += 0 //as far as selectedIndex is 0
```

Perhaps you're thinking about increment:

```
var selectedIndex = 0
selectedIndex++
```

After increment `selectedIndex = 1` as you expect

And if you might ask what is operator assignment complain. You could point a cursor to this line and press `Alt+Enter` code will automatically be replaced to following:

```
selectedIndex += 1
```

This is useful when you have something like

```
selectedIndex = selectedIndex + <some calculations/constant>
```

Equivalent is:

```
selectedIndex += <some calculations/constant>
```

Just shorter form of the same assignment